# Math operations inside log4j2.xml

Tags: xml, logging, log4j2

I want to add a custom pattern inside `log4j2.xml`.
In there I need to do some math operations like `multiplication (*)`, `modulo(%)`  of the log output.

For an example, assume I'm getting the Unix time in seconds as the log output. If I need to `multiply it by 1000`, how should I do it?

I tried out different ways of doing that. But it outputs the math operations as plain text.

Here is the example pattern I used in `log4j2.xml`. I tried out different ways of multiplications in there.

```xml
<Console name="stdout" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
    <PatternLayout>
        <pattern>%d{UNIX} %{1000*%d{UNIX}} (%d{UNIX})*1000 1000*(%d{UNIX}) %n</pattern>
    </PatternLayout>
</Console>
```

It outputs the plain text value. Not the values after multiplication.

```
1645687086 %{1000*1645687086} (1645687086)*1000 1000*(1645687086)
```

**So is there a way that I can do math operations like muliplication(*) and modulo(%) inside the xml tag itself?**

Answer (score 0):

Your question is probably a classical [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

If you want to print the timestamp in milliseconds from the Epoch use `%d{UNIX_MILLIS}`.

If, on the other hand, you are looking for [`PatternConverter`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-core/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/pattern/PatternConverter.html) that performs arithmetic substitution, there isn't one. The list of the available patterns can be found in the [documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html#Patterns).

However Log4j 2.x is very extensible and you can write and register your own pattern converter.

**Edit:** To create a new `PatternConverter` you can start from something like this:

```java
@Plugin(name = "math", category = "Converter")
@ConverterKeys({ "math" })
public class MathPatternConverter extends LogEventPatternConverter {

    private final List<PatternFormatter> patterns;

    public static MathPatternConverter newInstance(Configuration config, String[] options) {
        if (options.length < 1) {
            LOGGER.error("Incorrect number of options. Expected at least 1, received " + options.length);
            return null;
        }
        if (options[0] == null) {
            LOGGER.error("No pattern supplied.");
            return null;
        }
        final PatternParser parser = PatternLayout.createPatternParser(config);
        return new MathPatternConverter(parser.parse(options[0]));
    }

    protected MathPatternConverter(List<PatternFormatter> patterns) {
        super("math", "math");
        this.patterns = patterns;
    }

    @Override
    public void format(LogEvent event, StringBuilder toAppendTo) {
        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        patterns.stream().forEach(f -> f.format(event, sb));
        // sb contains a mathematical expression. You need to evaluate it.
        ... put your code here ...
    }
}
```

and use it as `%math{10 + 20}`. In order to register this plugin with Log4j 2.x proceed as described in the [plugins documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/plugins.html).

Comment: Actually no, I was just using `%d{UNIX}` as an example for the arithmetic operation. I already knew about the `%d{UNIX_MILLIS}`.